# validate form JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm trying to validate some of the field in my form.

and I want to check if they have input the correct area code of the required field.

The area code should be one of `212`, `313`, or `414`

This is homework so I can't use regular expression, and I'm not really asking for an answer but here is what I'm trying to use but non of them really worked for me

```
if (input.substr(0,2) != 212|| input.substr(0,2) != 313 || input.substr(0,2) != 414)
                Message += " <p>Sorry but you have enter wrong area code!!!</p>";
```

I've tried used `substring` `indexOf` but really I don't know non of them really correct in this case.

Is there anyway to validate but not with the regular expression?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to make sure input has a value? try calling `alert(input)` and see what happens.

Comment: The main problem is that substring(0, 2) only gives you 2 characters.  Not three.  But you should also switch the comparisons to strings and use !==

Comment: @KshitijMehta Yes the value I get was correct and I can validate the rest of the code except to make sure if the area code is correct.

Comment: @AutoSponge I'm going to try with 3 if that was the case.

Comment: @AutoSponge thanks for pointing out that and that was one of the problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="num"/>
<div id="msg"></div>

// This should run in a window.onload or $(document).ready() block
var num = document.getElementById('num'),
    msg = document.getElementById('msg');

num.onblur = function(){
    var areacodes = '212|313|414|',
        areacode = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '').substring(0,3),
        message = 'Area code validates.';

    if (areacode.length < 3 || areacodes.indexOf(areacode + '|') === -1) {
        message = "Sorry but you have entered an invalid area code.";
    }

    msg.innerHTML = message;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gfJWX/1

`input` I'm guessing is a `string` variable, and not a `DOM` note pointing to an `input` element.

Comment: Yes `input` was just the name I assign from the field value,

EDIT I tested and it doesn't work :(

Comment: I found out that the problem was `(0,2)` it suppose to be `(0,3)`

Comment: Yes, it should be three. I also added a normalizer for non-numeric characters: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gfJWX/

Comment: How is this the answer when he said "This is homework so I can't use regular expression,"?

Comment: @LarryBattle - The validation itself has nothing to do with regular expression, I added that to demonstrate a point that `(212)` wouldn't validate, although many would enter this. I also noticed I had the regex at the wrong spot. Technically, remove it and it will still "work", just won't match all forms of an entered area code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (input.substr(0,3) != 212|| input.substr(0,3) != 313 || input.substr(0,3) != 414)
      Message += " <p>Sorry but you have enter wrong area code!!!</p>";
```

I didn't test it though

Comment: Why is the first argument of substr increasing? input can be one of 212, 313, or 414.

Comment: I'm guessing that your code will validate `313` and `414` in a wrong position the area code will only be from index `0-2`

Comment: I thought the values should be entered at once, I've edited it.

Comment: @Chibuzo thanks but once I tried it still doesn't work I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work?

```
var str = input.trim().substr(0,3);
if ( !{212:1, 313:1, 414:1}[ str ] ){
    Message += " <p>Sorry but you have enter wrong area code!!!</p>";
}
```